# Network analyst functionality: assigning optimum location for two facilities

Tags: coordinate-system, network-analyst, routing

Hoping for some advice on using the network analyst tool to determine the optimal location for two facilities.

For context these would be a depot and tip locations servicing a set of households as demand points. The importance of having two locations optimally located is to minimise drive time from when a vehicle has to travel from households to tip (when at capacity) and also at the start/end of the day to return to the depot from households.

Any advice on an approach, or experience of doing similar would be great.

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question to specify, at least, _why_ the optimum location for the depot would be different from the optimum location for the tip (would it?).